# what is the right way to append all Js files using Jquery append

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization, render-blocking

I am attempting to load all js files using approach explained in this video @3:30 [Optimize your code: load code at the right time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDd6Y6Z50Mg)

I have implemented this approach in index.js as

```
<script>
 var scripts  = '<script src="./js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"/>'+
  '<script src="./js/jquery-ui.min.js"/>'+
  '<script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"/>'+
  '<script src="./js/index.js"/>';
    $(window).on("load",function(){
$("body").append(scripts)
});
</script>
```

also tried as in html head tag

```
 <script>
 var scripts  = '<script src="./js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"/>'+
  '<script src="./js/jquery-ui.min.js"/>'+
  '<script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"/>'+
  '<script src="./js/index.js"/>';
    $(window).on("load",function(){
$("body").append(scripts)
});
</script>
```

still it does not loads all js files which I am passing in script tags and not loading in network tab as well.

My question are

1. Is this really better approach to load all script like this and must be followed all the times?
2. If yes What I need to optimize above code so that it will load entire scripts and append to html?

Comment: You can't use `$(window).on("load"` if you haven't loaded jquery yet

Comment: Also script tags added through `append()` are not executed. You have to use [$.getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/), append an actual script dom element object, or use the native api

Comment: then I must load jquery and other files in script tag? then there is no benefit of loading just single external local file.

Comment: No, just jquery - and if you use a CDN, then there's a good chance your browser will already have it cached *and* processed - so loading from CDN will be quicker than late loading from local

Comment: @freedomn-m : I am not allowed to used CDN in my projects , I have to use Jquery, Jquery-UI, Bootstrap4.js and index.js. I have to add all script files in head and then index.js as append ?

Comment: No, just jquery if you want to use $.getScript or load with vanilla javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery isn't loaded yet so you can't use it. So i suggest you use a vanilla javascript solution. (Add as inline script tag right before the closing body tag `</body>`)

```
const scripts = [
  "./js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js",
  "./js/jquery-ui.min.js",
  "./js/bootstrap.min.js",
  "./js/index.js",
];

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  for(const script of scripts) {
    const scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
    scriptTag.src = script;
    document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
  }
});
```

EDIT: If you need the scripts to load in a particular order. You can use the "load" event to start the next one. See snippet below

```
const scripts = [
  "./js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js",
  "./js/jquery-ui.min.js",
  "./js/bootstrap.min.js",
  "./js/index.js",
];

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => loadScript(scripts, 0));

function loadScript(scripts, index) {
  if (!scripts[index]) return;

  const scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
  scriptTag.src = scripts[index];
  scriptTag.addEventListener("load", () => loadScript(scripts, index + 1));
  document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
}
```

Comment: I have to add <script src="./js/index.js"></script> in html then only it will load all script right ?

Comment: No - you don't put this script in `index.js` - you put it directly in the page by itself or load it with a `<script src` tag *separate* from the files you're including

Comment: @amarghodke No you should add this inside an inline script tag just before the closing </body> tag

Comment: After Random refresh I am getting error as Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in index.js pointing to document.ready and another error as Uncaught TypeError: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript. alternatively getting error and not working.

Comment: @amarghodke That is probably because some scripts finish earlier then jQuery. To solve this issue you can use the `load` callback. See new snippet

Comment: @Reyno I highly appreciated your kind effort,but Lighthouse Performance score in chrome still same as async , defer approach, I really don't know how Google itself telling this is best approach? It is just like normal script load.

Comment: @amarghodke Lighthouse just gives suggestions and is by no means perfect. But if you want to please Lighthouse you can add an async or defer script inside your head with the contents of one of the snippets.

Comment: In your opinion how would you place async or defer tag to js files eg. Async to Jquery index as defer can you please comment with all 4 tags?